# Is it possible to eliminate Moiré patterns from photos of screens?

Tags: post-processing, moire

I am very well aware of Moiré patterns and why they happen when taking photos of computer/phone screens. However on the website of some software projects there is a photo of someone using the product behind a screen (phone or computer). Yet I never see any Moiré pattern on the screen.

My knowledge of photo equipment is lacking. I believe most of these photos are just screencaptures photoshoped onto the screen.

My question is: is there any chance these photos are authentic? I am not asking to reveal the secrets of the trade, but is it even possible to eliminate Moiré patterns when taking photos without post-processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Moiré pattern you see is an artifact of the sampling frequency of the camera relative to that of the photographed display.  If the camera sensor's resolution isn't somewhat close to that of the projected image of the display, you won't see any Moiré, or the pattern you do see will be comparable in size to the screen itself.

One simple way to avoid this problem is to photograph the display subtly out of focus; this will blur the pixels together so that the space between them is less visible or completely lost, removing the sampling artifacts.  Another, and probably the way used in commercial product photography, is to replace the actual display with "simulated display" (as has been done for decades with television advertisements).  With modern editing software, it's not difficult to apply the geometric distortions (keystoning and foreshortening) to make the simulated display exactly fit the photographed screen bezel -- but you can start with a solid colors image or one with extremely high resolution that won't show artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, it is possible to capture a LED screen in-camera without moiré.

*The Mandalorian* show is filmed in a 270° cylindrical projection room, called "the volume" by the production team. Rather than using CGI in post, the scene's background elements are projected in real time on the LED screen, and captured at the same time as the actors in camera. There is no moiré in that show.